# pipe of stdout in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I've got the below statement gets one sentence from stdin and print the sentence (stdout).

```js
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

But what does the below statement means?

The below statement acts like the first statement.

(Receive data from the user and print it on the screen.)

What does the sentence below mean and why does this happen?

```js
process.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

what does it mean to pipe data from stdout, stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you can pipe `stdout` to `stdin`.  But it's not useful because there's no way to put data into `stdout`, and no way to get it out of `stdin`.

And, in some systems trying to read from `stdout` and / or write to `stdin` may throw an error.

`stdin` and `stdout` have been part of the UNIX / FreeBSD / Linux operating system for half a century now. Nodejs's `process` object simply exposes them. It's worth a bit of your time to learn how these fundamental OS building blocks work.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.
So, does the result of fetching from stdout vary from the platform because it is kind of undefined behavior?